# Ionic Zip cannot zip folder inside folder C#

Tags: c#, zip, directory

I am trying to zip a folder using IonicZip library in C#. It is able to zip .txt, .exe, .pdf etc. in the folder, but not able to zip folder in folder.

[image: Folder]

It is able to zip MusicLogs.txt and Video.exe but cannot Music folder.Music folder contains some folder also. It doesnt see Music folder even while debugging. My code is :

```
string zipPath = @"C:\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm") + ".zip"; // zipped file extracts here
string filename = @"E:\"; // the fodler which should be zipped. File must be exist

using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile())
{
    zipFile.Password = "asd";
    zipFile.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.PkzipWeak;
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(filename)) // this foreach is for getting all files in a folder. 
    {
        zipFile.AddFile(file, "YESMusic"); // set file
    }

    zipFile.Save(zipPath);

}
```

Where is the problem ? Need a change in AddFile function ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile())
{
    zipFile.Password = "asd";
    zipFile.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.PkzipWeak;          
    // Adding folders in the base directory
    foreach (var item in Directory.GetDirectories(filename))
    {
        string folderName = new DirectoryInfo(item).Name;
        zipFile.AddDirectory(item, folderName);
    }
    // Adding files in the base directory
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(filename))
    {
        zipFile.AddFile(file); 
    }
    zipFile.Save(zipPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working great!!!  I think I missed directory section. Thank you bro!

Comment: it's ok Bro..! happy to help you. have a nice day

Comment: Thanks, happy nice day